# Activity-based action bar/status bar visibility

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

I am trying to set up the `action bars` and the `status bar` within my app, however I have run into an issue. I did have it working, but it wasn't a clean way of doing things, so I decided to start over.

On the launch activity I want the status bar to be visible, with the pink background that I'm using throughout the app (no action bar). On the next view I want both the action bar and the status bar.

This is what I have within my launch activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    tools:context="com.andrewnwalker.mousetimes_california.ParkSelectActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        ...>

        <TextView
            .../>

        <TextView
            .../>

        <Button
            .../>

        <Button
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is what I have in the second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.andrewnwalker.mousetimes_california.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in content main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andrewnwalker.mousetimes_california.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        ...>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            ..../>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally in styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

It's probably a bit of a mess, but I'm pretty confused by the settings for styles and action bars. Can anyone suggest the changes I can make to do what I'm looking for?

At the moment the first activity has shows the status bar text, but no background colour, and the second activity shows the status bar and action bar, but it also contains a menu item, which I don't want.

Thanks!

Comment: For the code that you're showing, you haven't said what it is actually doing that is different that what you expect it to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited. Had intended to include that!

Comment: So the only things wrong so far are the color of the status bar and the presence of the menu on the action bar in the second screen?

Comment: @DougStevenson That, plus the launch screen status bar doesn't have a background colour.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar color conforming to material design is driven by the app's theme.  You can read the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar) about this, as there's not enough information here to know for sure what's going on.  You might be overriding the app theme on the first activity in the manifest or changing it somehow in the activity.  The first activity does have a peculiar layout.  There's no need to use CoordinatorLayout here if you don't have an action bar.  If you just need to scroll the inner LinearLayout, just use a ScrollView instead.

To remove the action bar menu, make sure that you're not returning a menu in onCreateOptionsMenu or modifying anything in onPrepareOptionsMenu.  Remove those methods if they're not needed.